# How can I receive the form by email when a client has sent me the form?

Tags: cognito-forms

To clarify, after they submit the form, how do I know that they filled it out. I need to receive it after that.

Can I receive this form by email right away or do I have to check my account to find my daily filled-out forms?

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  If you are asking how to include the form as a PDF in your email, look at your Notification settings and click on Attach Documents.

Comment: No. My question is the following:

After they submit the form....how do I know that they filled out the form...Can I receive this form by email right away or I have to check the account to fing my dayli forms filled out???

Comment: @Hermes: Please edit your question.

Comment: @Hermes - you will receive an email right away.